# Minimal Mongoose SSL connection code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to get a MongoDB connection to Node.js with Mongoose and Express to connect with SSL, but I can't connect even after knowing the keys work by connecting with Robomongo.

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express');

mongoose.set('debug', true);

// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {
        options: {
            ssl: true,
            port: 27017,
            user: 'xxxxxxxx',
            pass: 'xxxxxxxx_',
            sslValidate: false,
            checkServerIdentity: false,
            sslCA: fs.readFileSync('./config/sslcerts/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('./config/sslcerts/mongodb-cert.crt'),
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('./config/sslcerts/mongodb-cert.key'),
            sslPass: 'xxxxxx'
        },
    },
    function(err) {
        console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB!');
        console.log(err);
    });

// Init the express application
var app = require('express')(db);

app.listen(8443);
console.log('MEAN.JS application started on port ' + 8443);
```

Here is how I fire mongod:

> $ mongod --fork --logpath mongodblogs/mongodb.log --dbpath mongodb
>   --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /app/website/config/sslcerts/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile
>   /app/website/config/sslcerts/mongodb-cert.crt -v

Errors:

> Could not connect to MongoDB! MongoError: connection 0 to
>   localhost:27017 closed

same code, sometimes with another different error:

> Could not connect to MongoDB! MongoError: read ECONNRESET

Mongoose version: "raw": "mongoose@4.10.8",
Node version 4.8.0

Can someone help?

Comment: It looks like you're using the same key and cert on both ends of the connection? Have you verified you can connect to the server using the mongo client that ships with mongodb?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger Yes I can connect $ mongod with $ mongo from the command line with the same cert and keys